# How many cluster must i created on MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I want to implement MongoDB transactional. But there is a term that must not single alone server. So, how many clusters must I create to an implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB Atlas won't let you create a standalone server, so any Atlas cluster should be able to use transactions.

Comment: thanks for your explanation

Comment: what is mean about standalone server? is if i create a server on digital ocean VPS, it standalone server?

Comment: When using MongoDB you can have a 'standalone server' where a single server holds all the data or a `replica set` where several servers hold the same data for redundancy.